# Differential with sub y = ux

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am differentiating a first order DE. I want to use the substitution y = ux and the differential $dy = udx +xdu$. I thought $dy = u + xdu$ because $dx = x$. I thought I am differentiating with respect to x.

I would appreciate any feedback. thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$y=\underbrace{ux}_{\color{red}{\text {prodct of 2 function}s}}$$
Differentiate
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=x\frac {du}{dx}+u=u'x+u$$
Multiply by dx
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=x\frac {du}{dx}+u$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}dx=x\frac {du}{dx}dx+udx$$
$${dy}=x {du}+udx$$

Like when you differntiate any product of two functions
$$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$

Comment: Right but my textbook says to sub dy = xdu + udx? Do you know why?

Comment: multiply by dx simply

Comment: Yea okay, thanks

Comment: i added some lines @Kovs95

Answer (score 0):

You wrote : " I thought $dy = u + xdu$ because $dx = x$. "

This is a big mistake because $dx$ is an infinitesimal, that is "something infinitely small" and $x$ is a finite value, hence not infinitely small in general (except when $x=0$).

Thus $dx=x$ is a non-sens.

May be, you can better understand this on the "physical" sens :

$dx$ is then understood as an infinitely small variation of $x$. So, one cannot confuse $x$ with it's variation $dx$.

$du$ is understood as an infinitely small variation of $u$.

$dy$ is understood as an infinitely small variation of $y$.

The rule says that the variation of $y=$($u$ multiplied by $x$) is the sum of two infinitesimal variations :

- One : ($u$ multiplied by $dx$) $=u\,dx$ ,
- Second : ($x$ multiplied by $du$) $=x\,du$,

$$dy=u\,dx+x\,du$$

How can this rule be understood on the "physical" sens ?

When $u$ is increased to $(u+du)$ and $x$ is increased to $(x+dx)$ the product $y=ux$ increases to 
$$y+dy=(u+du)(x+dx)$$
$$y+dy=ux+u\,dx+x\,du+du\,dx$$
$$y+dy=y+u\,dx+x\,du+du\,dx$$
$$dy=u\,dx+x\,du+du\,dx$$
$du\,dx$ is the product of two infinitesimals, which order of magnitude is infinitely smaller that the infinitesimals themselves. Thus, it is negligible.
$$dy=u\,dx+x\,du$$

Answer (score 0):

$$dy(u, x)=\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}}du+\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}}dx=xdu+udx$$

Comment: Note: There is a typo in your $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}$ which should be $\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}}$. Of course, you are right but I doubt that the OP can understand the argument with partial derivatives, considering the level of knowledge denoted by his assertion $dx=x$.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I see...

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives are obtained from differentials

$$dy = udx +xdu$$

by direct division as if they are algebraic ... numerator/denominator in a fraction.

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = u + x \dfrac{\,du}{dx}$$

Derivatives are divided quantities or quotients of infinitesimally small  (called differentials) bits when the function has a slope that varies.

Comment: For the sake of precision, note that this manipulation only makes sense if $\mathrm{d}u$ is a multiple of $\mathrm{d}x$, and similarly for $\mathrm{d}y$. (e.g. when $u$ can be expressed as the value of a differentiable function applied to $x$)